# Code that run at compile-time vs code that run at runtime

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm new to Vue and Webpack. I have recently generated a static web app using vue-cli, and played with it for a while. Here is a snippet in `src/components/hello.vue`:

```
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: process.env.NODE_ENV
    }
  }
}
```

I recognized that the expression `process.env.NODE_ENV` is evaluated at compile-time. My questions are

1. how can I tell if an expression is evaluated at compile-time or at runtime (i.e. on the browsers) since it is a valid javascript expression in either case?
2. can I define functions that run at compile-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is made possible with [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), which essentially works as a "find and replace" operation in your code.

Simply add it to your webpack config like this:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"',
    })
  ]
}
```

This will replace all occurances of `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your code with `"development"`. If you combine this with the [`UglifyJsPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/), then it will take care of removing the resulting dead code from your build:

```js
// Original code

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  alert('development build');
} else {
  alert('non-development build');
}

// After DefinePlugin

if ("development" === 'development') {
  alert('development build');
} else {
  alert('non-development build');
}

// After Uglify

alert('development build');
```

> How can I tell if an expression is evaluated at compile-time or at runtime (i.e. on the browsers) since it is a valid javascript expression in either case?

The object you pass to the constructor of `DefinePlugin` contains the code definitions that will be translated at compile time.

> Can I define functions that run at compile-time?

I don't think so, at least not within the code being built (but you can write functions that are a part of your build script). It might be an optimization that Uglify can do, but it would be pretty intense.

**EDIT:** [`val-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/val-loader) can generate source code at build time.